# Using sed/awk, I need to remove all lines in a file from the first occurrence of pattern1 up-to (but not including) the last occurrence of pattern2

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Using sed/awk, I need to remove all lines in a file from the first occurrence of pattern1 up-to (but not including) the last occurrence of pattern2.

Consider the following text:

```
    <entity name="good">
    </entity>
    <entity name="bad">
    stuff to delete
    </entity>
    <entity name="bad">
    stuff to remove
    </entity>
    <entity name="bad2">
    </entity>
    <entity name="deleteMe2">
    </entity>
    <entity name="bad2">
    </entity>
    <entity name="good">
    </entity>
```

I would like the following outcome

```
<entity name="good">
</entity>
<entity name="bad2">
</entity>
<entity name="good">
</entity>
```

I know how to do a range in sed, but can't figure out how to match the last occurrence of 'bad2' and not include it in the delete.  The below of course will not work as it will match the first bad2 and not remove the 'deleteme2' or 2nd occurrenc of 'bad2'.

```
sed -i '/<entity name="bad"/,/<entity name="bad2"/d' file.xml
```

There can be hundreds of 'bad'/'deleteMe2'/'bad2' lines in the file I am dealing with, so a simple line count won't work.  I am fine if this is multiple commands (it does not have to be just a single one), but the more efficient the better because the file being modified can be quite large.  As well, the -i is because I want to do an in place delete of the lines between.

NOTE: I am more familiar with SED than I am with AWK, but I am open to all the help I can get:)

Comment: Looks a lot like XML. Is it XML? Because if so, it's almost certainly better to use a parser.

Comment: Yes, it is XML, and I totally get not using sed/awk to modify XML, but the XML definition is quite simple in this case.  Literally what you see above with some additional text.  One constraint I didn't really mention is that I will most likely have to do this on a Windows box, most likely with gnused or gawk.  I will consider perl as an option if there is not a way to do what I am asking in sed/awk.

Comment: When you repeat the title in your question, the question is more clear. I skipped the title first and got confused.

Comment: Which sections do you need to delete vs keep?  It's not clear from your "outcome", which deletes 2 bad sections, 1 bad2 section, and 1 deleteMe2 section.

Comment: @Brian Delete the first line with bad and all following lines until the last bad2 section is completed. Everything in between is bad.

Comment: I will suggest `python`'s `xml.etree.ElementTree`. Because I don't understand the exact requirement, I can't post an answer.

Comment: @WalterA done, thnx for the advice.

Comment: @Brian what WalterA said, it is the LAST occurrence of 'bad2' that I am interested in keeping.

Comment: Strawberry perl ships with an XML parser.

Comment: Using "XML is simple" is a poor reason to create a complicated regex, not least because there are lots of ways of saying the same thing in XML - especially in terms of white space and unary tags. These can one day break mysteriously, making your code brittle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    if (/"bad"/ && !begFnr) {
        begFnr = FNR
    }
    if (/"bad2"/) {
        endFnr = FNR
    }
    next
}
(FNR < begFnr) || (FNR >= endFnr)

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
<entity name="good">
</entity>
<entity name="bad2">
</entity>
<entity name="good">
</entity>
```

Comment: This looks like the most easily understood solution but I can't get it to replace anything in the file.  Perhaps I am doing this wrong...  I attempted to escape the " with a \" in the case above because I believe they are special characters and still did not get it to perform the 'delete'/'replace'.  Is there anything else in the above that I could be missing/errant?  One last question, the 'awk -f tst.awk file file' what is the second 'file' for?

Comment: `"`s are not special characters in a regexp, they do not need to be escaped. The file has to be listed twice because it requires 1 pass to figure out where the **last** occurrence of `bad2` is located and the second pass to actually do the line selection/deletion based on that. If you use the script as-is, call it as shown, on the input file you posted, it WILL produce the output shown so if it's not producing the desired output then you are doing something wrong and I can't guess what.

Comment: Well crap, maybe i should just do what I am told rather that trying to 'fix' something that is not broken.  This does work after using both 'file' values and removing the escapes.  Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: You're welcome. I think you'll find that doing things like this in awk is orders of magnitude simpler and easier to understand than doing them in sed!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like XML to me, so I would *strongly* suggest that `regex` isn't the tool for the job. Use a parser instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'your_file.xml' ) ;
$_ -> delete for $twig -> findnodes ( '//entity[@name="bad"]');
$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');
$twig -> print;
```

Or perhaps more comprehensively:

```
for my $entity ( $twig -> findnodes ( '//entity') ) {
   if ( $entity -> att('name') eq "bad"
   or   $entity -> att('name') eq "deleteMe2" ) {
           $entity -> delete; 
   }
}
```

To delete only the first instance of 'bad2' you can just call `findnodes` once, and delete the first 'hit'.

Comment: Totally understand about regex not loving XML. The requirement I am working with is awk/sed based on this being easily ported to windows.  The folks I am passing this off to are not as familiar with perl as they are with sed/awk, which is why I asked for that in the question specifically.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR&&/\"bad\"/&&!s{s=NR;next} 
          NR==FNR&&/\"bad2\"/{e=NR;next} 
          NR!=FNR && (FNR<s || FNR>=e)' xml{,}

    <entity name="good">
    </entity>
    <entity name="bad2">
    </entity>
    <entity name="good">
    </entity>
```

I guess can be simplified further. Two pass script to mark the line numbers first and print the second time.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed '/bad/,$!b;/bad2/h;//!H;$!d;g;/bad2/!d' file
```

Lines that are not between `bad` and the end of the file, print as normal. Otherwise store those lines in the hold space overwriting those stored lines when matching `bad2`. Delete all lines but the last, replacing it with the contents of the hold space. Delete the line unless it matches `bad2`.